# Entity Framework 6 - unable to update xml

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework

I have used EF code first from database wizard to create db access inside my project.

I have entity that represents table:

```
    [Table("__Item")]
public partial class Item
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key()]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "xml")]
    public string documentXML { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public byte XmlVersion { get; set; }
}
```

And i'm trying to add new record:

```
            var db = new Model();

        db.Item.Add(
            new Item()
            {
                documentXML = "<root/>",
                XmlVersion = 3
            });

        db.SaveChanges();
```

That brings the exception:

**The data types xml and nvarchar(max) are incompatible in the equal to operator.**

The reason for that is a way sp_executesql is constructedb by EF:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[__Item]([documentXML], [XmlVersion])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [id]
FROM [dbo].[__Item]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [id] = scope_identity() AND [documentXML] = @0 AND [XmlVersion] = @1',N'@0 varchar(max) ,@1 tinyint',@0='<root/>',@1=3
```

EF forces param @0 to be varchar(max) instead of XML type.

**How to properly define Entity that represents table with XML column to have ability of updating that column?**

IT MAN

Answer (score 1):

Well it took me a wile but i have figure it out:

Originally my table didn't have identity column. When i have generated Entities some of the columns were marked as "[Key]" and used for data comparssion so that Entity Framework could resolve proper "id" during INSERT operation.

When i have added identity column and removed [Key] attributes from documentXML and XmlVersion, SaveChanges worked as expected.